# 'Output argument "arraydata" (and maybe others) not assigned during call' error recieved when using sysic

Tags: matlab, control-theory

When using the sysic command to create an interconnected system as shown in the below code;

```
% Random systems for example
scaledPlant=rss(4,4,4);
WControl=rss(4,4,4);
WError=rss(4,4,4);

% actual problem code
systemnames = '  scaledPlant WControl WError'; 
inputvar = '[r(4);  u(4)]'; 
outputvar = '[WControl; WError;r[1]- scaledPlant[1]]';
input_to_scaledPlant = '[u]';
input_to_WError = '[r-scaledPlant]';
input_to_WControl = '[u]';
sysoutname = 'P';
cleanupsysic= 'yes';
sysic
```

where scaledPlant, WControl and WError are all 4 input 4 output models

I recieve the following error

```
 Error in ==> sysic>LOCALpass1 at 406  
 err = 0;

 ??? Output argument "arraydata" (and maybe others) not assigned during
 call to "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\toolbox\robust\robust\sysic.m
 (LOCALpass1)".
```

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by using the wrong kind of brackets to indicate signal number, [square brackets] are being used but (Parentheses) should be used. See [the official documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/robust/ref/sysic.html) for an example of correct usage

The corrected code is as follows;

```
systemnames = '  scaledPlant WControl WError';  %corrector1 corrector2 
inputvar = '[r(4);  u(4)]'; %<-- here the number in Parentheses shows the number of signals
outputvar = '[WControl; WError;r(1)- scaledPlant(1)]'; %<-- here it shows the signal number
input_to_scaledPlant = '[u]';
input_to_WError = '[r-scaledPlant]';
input_to_WControl = '[u]';
sysoutname = 'P';
cleanupsysic= 'yes';
sysic
```